# MOM and EOM in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

What is the most sample and practical way to know the MOM (middle of month) and EOM (end of month) in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005? (without doing a select case / switch)

EOM is the last day of the month, and MOM is the last day of the fortnight. It seems to be 15 for every month except on February.

Also I need to take care the leap-year, Holidays, business day option, etc. Like linux.

Comment: Why can you not do `CASE`?

Comment: because i don't have the possibilities for leap-year, bussinnes day, not holiday, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex date and time functions, use a user defined table-valued function and filter the results from it:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2010/07/19/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions.aspx

There are a number of ways to do this, but this is one I prefer.

Comment: This can have performance issues as the entire output of the function has to be processed for a join.  Query plans involving tvfs can be quite inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

In a data warehouse with a date dimension it's often common practice to annotate the dimension with this sort of thing.  You can use a TVF to generate the initial data but perisisting it in a table will be faster for most purposes.  There's no particular reason that this technique could not be applied to a transactional application.